# ObservableList does not work is I expected

Tags: javafx, imageview, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableList<ImageView>` that I want to refresh every time I proceed with some action. By default, I have put three images in the array list and this is how I remove the last one after some action:

```
list.remove(list.size()-1;
```

After removing the item, I call a method that draws this list; but when there is only one image left it doesn't disappear. I already tried to return empty `Node` if the list is empty, but it didn't change anything. Also found out that the list actually empty in debugger. Any idea why?

EDIT:

```
ObservableList<ImageView> ammoList;
HBox ammoHBox;
...
private HBox addAmmo(){
    ammoHBox = new HBox();
    if(ammoList.isEmpty()) return hbox; //dont work
    ammoHBox.getChildren().addAll(naboje);
    ammoHBox.setSpacing(10);
    return ammoHBox;
}
```

This I call every time ammoList has changed.

Comment: If you have confirmed with a debugger that the list is indeed empty the problem is almost definitely in the part where you draw the contents of the list. Please include this part, along with any other relevant parts of your code.

Comment: What is `hbox` (the value you return)? It is not defined in the code snippet. Did you mean to return `ammoHBox`?

Comment: What is `naboje` and how is your method used? Furthermore if you already store the `HBox` in the scenegraph `HBox` as a field, why don't you modify the existing one instead of recreating it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `list` is a [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true), perhaps the one backing the [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html). In effect,

```
 ObservableList<ImageView> ammoList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
```

While changes to `ammoList` *will* be reported, changes to `list` will *not*. Verify that you alter the `ObservableList` using its [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#remove-int-int-) method, which take two parameters, and not the corresponding `List` method, which takes one.